# How to get rid of special characters after generating sql statements using for xml

Tags: sql-server, select-for-xml

I have generated insert statements for audit trail using `for xml` and it generates the correct insert statements. See below is what gets generated.

This is what `Print @SQL` outputs:

```
INSERT INTO [AuditLog]&#x0D;
                (&#x0D;
                [TableName]&#x0D;
                ,[ColumnName]&#x0D;
                ,[Value]&#x0D;
                ,[Action]&#x0D;
                ,[TimeStamp]&#x0D;
                )           &#x0D;
                SELECT &#x0D;
                    'Book'&#x0D;
                    ,'BookID'&#x0D;
                    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), BookID)&#x0D;
                    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), 1)&#x0D;
                    ,getdate()&#x0D;
                FROM INSERTED;&#x0D;
                INSERT INTO [AuditLog]&#x0D;
                (&#x0D;
                [TableName]&#x0D;
                ,[ColumnName]&#x0D;
                ,[Value]&#x0D;
                ,[Action]&#x0D;
                ,[TimeStamp]&#x0D;
                )           &#x0D;
                SELECT &#x0D;
                    'Book'&#x0D;
                    ,'c_Name'&#x0D;
                    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), c_Name)&#x0D;
                    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), 1)&#x0D;
                    ,getdate()&#x0D;
                FROM INSERTED;&#x0D;
                INSERT INTO [AuditLog]&#x0D;
                (&#x0D;
                [TableName]&#x0D;
                ,[ColumnName]&#x0D;
                ,[Value]&#x0D;
                ,[Action]&#x0D;
                ,[TimeStamp]&#x0D;
                )           &#x0D;
                SELECT &#x0D;
                    'Book'&#x0D;
                    ,'c_Author'&#x0D;
                    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), c_Author)&#x0D;
                    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), 1)&#x0D;
                    ,getdate()&#x0D;
                FROM INSERTED;&#x0D;
                INSERT INTO [AuditLog]&#x0D;
                (&#x0D;
                [TableName]&#x0D;
                ,[ColumnName]&#x0D;
                ,[Value]&#x0D;
                ,[Action]&#x0D;
                ,[TimeStamp]&#x0D;
                )           &#x0D;
                SELECT &#x0D;
                    'Book'&#x0D;
                    ,'c_Price'&#x0D;
                    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), c_Price)&#x0D;
                    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), 1)&#x0D;
                    ,getdate()&#x0D;
                FROM INSERTED;
```

However when I try to execute using `EXECUTE(@SQL)` I get an error message:

> Incorrect syntax near '&'.

Comment: This is NOT valid sql syntax. You have some xml remnants in there. You need to provide us a bit more detail before anybody can really offer much help here.

Comment: I know that and that's what I am asking how can I avoid having those special characters in generated text so I can execute it.

Comment: Well...we don't know how you are generating it. That would be the best place to start.

Comment: The `&#x0D;` is there because of a carriage return.  If you post your code that you're using to generate the string, then we could probably help you determine why you're getting the carriage return codes in your output.

Answer (score 0):

Unbelievably, I found really simple solution. I used **COALESCE** function to generate dynamic insert statements and I don't see any special characters as it would otherwise using **for xml**